# How to get 1 value from a variable with multiple value in environment variable inside command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

We can get specific variable value by using **%VARIABLENAME%** in command prompt, but how to get specific value if the variable has 2 value (seperated by semicolon **;**) for example: **value1;value2**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the value string.
Like so:

```
for "delims=;" /f %%i in (%VARIABLENAME%) do (
 echo %%i
)
```

Inside the for block you can use the %%i as variable identifier for the current value.
Maybe you want test on a specific value? Then do something like this instead of the simple `echo` above:

```
if "%%1" == "someValue" (
   ...myCode...
) else (
  ... some other code ...
)
```

Check out `for /?` and `if /?` on the commandline if you need more details.

Hope this helps, good luck :)